# Reading XML Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have following C# code to read values from XML file. But when I expand the result, it says “Enumeration yielded no results”

**Questions**

1. What is the issue here?
2. How to fix this?
3. How to read the value of "family" element

**Note**: I have seen similar questions in stack overflow and other forums and tried the recommendations already.

**C#**

```
        XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"Test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
        IEnumerable<XElement> childList = from el in doc.Elements() select el;

        IEnumerable<XElement> result = childList.Elements(ns+ "assignedPerson");
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <typeId root="2.16.840.1.1" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
  <languageCode code="en-US"/>
  <author>
    <time value="334455"/>
    <assignedAuthor>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883" extension="771544"/>
      <code codeSystem="2.16.840.1" codeSystemName="Provider Codes" code="207R00000X" displayName="Nephrology"/>
      <addr use="WP">
        <city>East Point</city>
      </addr>
      <telecom use="WP" value="tel:(xxx)xxx-xxxx"/>
      <assignedPerson>
        <name>
          <prefix>Mrs</prefix>
          <given>Test</given>
          <family>Martin</family>
          <suffix>NP</suffix>
        </name>
      </assignedPerson>
    </assignedAuthor>
  </author>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Comment: There is no `assignedPerson` that is a child of the `doc.Elements()` collection.

Comment: If it still doesn’t work, maybe you could omit the namespace.

Comment: You're not at the scope of the parent node of assignedPerson.

Comment: @Nikolaus - Omitting the namespace wouldn't work. Namespaces are important.

Comment: @Enigmativity I thought namespaces are only important, if there are redundant types... it was only a guess.

Comment: @Nikolaus - No, they are always enforced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `assignedPerson` that is a child of the `doc.Elements()` collection.

Try this instead:

```
    XNamespace ns = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
    IEnumerable<XElement> result =
        doc
            .Descendants(ns + "assignedPerson")
            .Descendants(ns + "family");
```